Как настроить Vite/React для запуска билда из index.html
Хочу запускать билд проекта Vite/ReactJS без npm run preview, просто даблкликом по index.html в папке билда.
Вручную это можно сделать заменив в index.html type="module" на defer="defer" и удалив crossorigin и добавив точку к путям в scr и href
Так же вручную нужно в сбилженом js файле добавит точку для путей локальных изображений
Если в конфиге vite указать base:'./', то точки для путей в index.html добавляются но в файле js пути к изображениям указываются совсем странно и их нужно опять же вручную исправлять 
Скорее всего есть какой-то простой способ но я уже довольно долго ищу в решения и пока ничего толкового нету
